# Microchip Advanced Part Selector - Difference between CCP, PWM Outputs, PWM Channels

Tags: pic

I want to select a PIC with at least 4 PWM channels. I was looking at the [Microchip Advanced Part Selector (MAPS)](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx) and I got confused with Digital Peripherals options, there was Max PWM Outputs, PWM Chan, Std PWM, CCP and others, whats the difference, also why there are two selectable values for each one, is this a range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the two coulombs are a range. The right coulomb is the maximum and the left coulomb is minimum.

PICs have lots of ways to generate PWMs. What you are seeing is all the different kinds of modules that PICs contain. The module depends on the family of PIC and the model of PIC in the family.

PWM channels refer to how many independent time bases you can have. This covers both independent PWM periods and duty cycles.

Max PWM outputs refers to how many pins a PWM can come out of. Some processors can multiplex a single PWM to many pins.

Comment: If I need at least same frequency(or the option to multiple frequencys) but different pins with different duty cycle which one I need?

Comment: @Pulse9 What PIC line are you looking at? If you want super duper flexibility a dsPIC33 will fill just about any PWM need. If you want to look for yourself sort by PWM channel.

Comment: Im looking for a cheap pic, 18F or 16F series will be great

Comment: @Pulse9 there are a few pic16 and pic18 that will fill your needs.